How to deserialize JSON API response using generics when the data could be singular or list of items
Given a simple class which represents a API response as follows:
Let's say we know the endpoint data could be a map or a list, and we specify the generic type:
class APIResponse<T> {
  final int? statusCode;
  final T? data;
  final APIError? error;

  APIResponse({this.statusCode, this.data, this.error});

  factory APIResponse.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json, T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) fromJsonData
  ) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      if (json['data'] is List) {
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }      
    }
  }
}

It works when the resource returned is a single object as follows, as T = User and T fromJsonData also returns T = User
APIResponse<User>

However if the we want it to decode a list:
APIResponse<List<User>>

The problem happens when we are expecting a List but fromJsonData function passed in only decodes a single object, e.g. List vs User
I currently solve this issue by adding another field: List<T>? dataList
Is there a more elegant way to solve this in Dart? Perhaps there are better third party JSON decoders?

The problem is not the JSON-decoding.  The decoding is fine... you get a tree of Map and List and primitive.  The problem is turning that tree into reasonably shaped objects so that you can use named and typed properties, and that still has to be mostly by hand.

Yes you're right though I feel like I don't have these issues say with other built in JSON packages such as the one in Go, where it can handle []User and User pretty easily without much intervention on my end.

Go is easier apparently because there's reflection.  dart:mirror has been effectively gone for a long time, and is not coming back.  Maybe macros will help.
